# SQL: How to get case depending data while two different information are saved in the same column

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

I have the following 2 tables:

Table: Person

```
Columns: id | person_typ | salutation | firstnam | lastname
row1:     1 | c          |...         |...       |...
row2:     1 | e          |...         |...       |...
```

Table: Receipt

```
Columns: id | receiptnr
row1:     1 |...
row2:     1 |...
```

I need to get the following output:

```
employee_name | amount_of_customer_visits|
```

The names have no problem. The amount has to be 1. I get the amount with a simple query:

```
count(receiptnr) AS amount_of_customer_visits
WHERE amount_of_customer_visits = 1
```

The problem I run into is that the names of the customers and the names of the employees are in the same column. I really don't know how to solve that. I tried everything I could possibly find. I tried to do it with `WHERE`:

```
WHERE person_typ = e
```

But you would probably need more than one select statement. So I tried with `UNION` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you post the full table definitions and full SQL that you attempted? It isn't much help trying to work with fragments.

Comment: @HelloWorld . . . Is the number of visits somehow related to one of the tables (which are called `person` and `receipt`)?  If so, it is not obvious.